# Jquery - iterate through all xml tags

Tags: jquery

how to loop over all tags in a xml

i have a php that generates xmls like the next one

```
<register>
  <name>peter</name>
  <age>12</age>
</register> 
<register>
  <name>mary</name>
  <age>20</age>
</register>
```

so i receive this xml (this works fine)

```
$.ajax({success: function(xml) {  

   $(xml).find('register').each (function() 
   { 
     alert($(this).find('name').text()) // works fine, shows peter then mary on the next loop of "each"



     // But if i dont know the tag names (name,age) for each register ?     

     // Something like

      $(this).nodes().each .... // 
 alert($(this).tagName);  // i wanna show "name" & "age", how can i get the tag names inside each register in my xml sample tree?

   });    

}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to look at the `children()` function, among others. See the [jQuery traversal documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing) for more info on the functions.

Comment: thanks for your fast asnwer but still i cant do it =( (and im sad ...)

in the jquery help says 
var $kids = $(e.target).children();

but still .. that prolly gives me some object/array with the childs but 
how do i get the tagName of each children ?

this didnt work
$(this).children().each(function() {alert($(this).tagName);}); // didnt work

this neither, shows all methods/att 
var childs = $(this).children();
 for(key in childs) alert(key);

Comment: finally ..
var $childs = $(this).children();   
var length = $childs.length;   
while(length--) alert($childs[length].tagName);   
thanks you very much

Answer (score 11):

This link provides a good example for use of iterating through xml

```
xml.find('result').find('permissionDetails').each(function(){
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        var tagName=this.tagName;
        var val=$(this).text();
        if(val==1){
            $('input:checkbox[name='+tagName+']').attr('checked',true);
        }
        else if(val==0){
            $('input:checkbox[name='+tagName+']').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    })
});
```

http://anasthecoder.blogspot.in/2012/02/looping-through-xml-with-jquery.html