# javascript jquery iterate simple XML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to iterate over XML items.

Sample XML:

```
<items>
    <name>234</name>
    <email></email>
    <phone></phone>
    <phone2></phone2>
    <phone7>33</phone7>
</items>
```

I tried a lot of combinations but without any success. For example:

```
var xml=' <items><name>234</name> <email></email><phone></phone></items>'

$(xml).find('items\').each(function() {
  alert($(this).text() + ':' + $(this).value());
});
```

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735026/jquery-iterate-through-all-xml-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is that in your example, `<items>...</items>` is the root node — it **is** the `xml` variable.  So, if you want its children, you can just do:

```
var xml='<items><name>234</name> <email></email><phone></phone></items>';
$(xml).children.each(function() {
  alert(this.nodeName + ':' + $(this).text());
});
```

And if you want the `<items>` node itself, you can do simply:

```
var xml='<items><name>234</name> <email></email><phone></phone></items>';
$(xml).each(function() {
  alert(this.nodeName + ':' + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: thank you very much
ps 
small typo should be children() instead of children

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml=' <items><name>234</name> <email></email><phone></phone></items>';

$(xml).find('items').each(function() {
alert(this.nodeName + ':' + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: `find('items')` doesn't, but `filter('items')` does, in case you care

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
$(xml).find('items').each(function(){
  var name = $(this).find('name').text();
  alert(name);
});
```