# Find an xml element by html element class/id

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, find, compare

i need some help with my script. I want to find in my xml file some element with the same name as an html list class. Than i want to compare them and do something... This is my code. Thx for help from the mountain.

```
var class_main_content = $('.main_content ul').find(this.class);
if((class_main_content) == $(xml).find(class_main_content).text()){
    $(this).find("element").each(function(){
        var name = $(this).find("name").text();
        var image = $(this).find("image").text();
        var level = $(this).find("level").text();
        $("#rounded_items").append('<li id="'+ level +'"><img src="'+ image +'" class="image"/><span>'+ name +'</span></li>')
    });        
}
```

my xml:

```
<programy_gotowe>
    <element>
        <image>img/icons/01-02/ciasta.png</image>
        <name>Ciasta</name>
        <level>pg_ciasta</level>
    </element>
</programy_gotowe>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate though the xml ,you can get help from this question

[Jquery - iterate through all xml tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735026/jquery-iterate-through-all-xml-tags)

Answer (score 0):

ok, maybe this way will be better

```
        var class_main_content = $('.main_content ul').find(this.class);
        var xml_element_name = $(xml).find(class_main_content).text();
        if ((class_main_content) == xml_element_name){
            $('.main_content ul').remove();
        }
```

can anybody help?